# How to access $project field in next line in mongo db aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

```
db.test.aggregate({
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    data: 1,
    numOfDocument: "120",
    entity_doc_count: numOfDocument
  }
})
```

How to assign **numOfDocument** filed value to  **entity_doc_count**
Thank you.

Comment: I have numOfDocument 120 value...just to assign to new column

Comment: {"numOfProject": 100,
    "numOfCompletedProject" :  50,
    "completionPercentage" : { "$floor" : {"$multiply":[{"$divide":[numOfCompletedProject,numOfProject]},100]} }

Comment: In above code i just want to calculate percentage depending upon two fileds

Comment: Please clarify your question by editing it instead of commenting